# Case operator where value is unrestricted

Tags: vba

I want to modify the code so the entered value is unrestricted.

The exception is the numbers from 11 to 14 рублей.

In other cases, the choice is made by the Case operator, but the remainder after dividing the number by 10 is analyzed.

For the remainder equal to 1, the name is "рубль(ruble)"
For the remainder equal to 2, 3, 4, the name is "рубля(rublya)"
For the remainder equal to 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 the name is "рублей(rubles)".

```vb
Dim Num As Integer
Dim Text As String
Num = InputBox ("Enter a number from 0 to 10", "Enter a number")
Select Case Num
    Case 1
        MsgBox "Correct" & Num & "рубль(ruble)", VbYesNo + vbInformation, ""
    Case 2, 3, 4
        MsgBox "Correct" & Num & "рубля(rublya)", VbYesNo + vbInformation, ""
    Case 5 To 10, 0
        MsgBox "Correct" & Num & "рублей(rubles)", VbYesNo + vbInformation, ""
    Case else
        MsgBox "Number entered incorrectly", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, ""
End Select
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to achieve. Could you provide some examples of numbers entered and the expected results of these? Also, what is the point of `vbYesNo` ?

Comment: There is no sense in vbYesNo. 
For example, when I enter the number 3, the result is "Correct 3 rublya". When I enter the number 1, the result is "Correct 1 ruble". When I enter the number 14, the result is "Correctly 14 rubles." The essence of the task is that when entering numbers that end in 1, the name will be "ruble". Numbers ending in 2,3,4 should be named "Rublya". Numbers ending in 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 must be named "rubles"

Comment: I'd change `vbYesNo` to `vbOKOnly`

Answer (score 1):

```
If Num >= 11 And Num <= 14 Then
    MsgBox "Correct" & Num & "рублей(rubles)", VbYesNo + vbInformation, ""
Else
    Select Case Num Mod 10
        Case 1
            MsgBox "Correct" & Num & "рубль(ruble)", VbYesNo + vbInformation, ""
        Case 2, 3, 4
            MsgBox "Correct" & Num & "рубля(rublya)", VbYesNo + vbInformation, ""
        Case 5 To 9, 0
            MsgBox "Correct" & Num & "рублей(rubles)", VbYesNo + vbInformation, ""
    End Select
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain how the exceptions, eleven to fourteen, are to be expressed. However, the function below presents you with a flexible solution that you can adapt in many ways.

```
Function Rubles(ByVal Qty As Integer) As String

    Dim Q       As Integer      ' derived quantity
    Dim Arr()   As String       ' result array
    Dim i       As Variant      ' array index
    
    Q = Qty Mod 10
    If Qty > 10 And Qty < 15 Then
        Arr = Split("Rubles,11 rubles,12 rubles,13 rubles,14 rubles", ",")
        i = Application.Match(Q, Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 1)
        If i > 4 Then i = 0
    Else
        Arr = Split("rubles,ruble,rublya", ",")
        i = Application.Match(Q, Array(1, 2, 5), 1)
        If IsError(i) Then i = 0
        If i > 2 Then i = 0
    End If
    
    Rubles = Arr(i)
End Function
```

At the core of the code is this worksheet function which you can try out to adjust the code.

```
= INDEX({"ruble","rublya","rubles"}, MATCH(A2, {1,2,5}, 1)
```

The function will return "ruble" if A2 = 1. It will return "rublya" if A2 >1 but <5 and "rubles" in all other cases, except that it will return an error if A2 = 0. The code catches that error and converts it to 0. It also uses a slightly different Index array where Array(0) = "rubles".

The same principle is then expanded to deal with the numbers 11 to 14 distinctly from all others.

The code is designed as a function where the argument is equivalent to A2 in the worksheet variation just explained. In fact, you can call it from the worksheet: `=Rubles(A2)` will return the the correct form of the word if A2 holds a number and the function is in a standard code module. You can also call the function from within your code with `Rubles(14)` to return "14 rubles". Please replace my English expressions in the arrays with what you need in Russian.